# In which macOS version was the -json flag/switch added in system_profiler?

Tags: system-profiler

Which version of macOS (OS X) first included `-json` switch in `system_profiler`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was introduced in Catalina.

[JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) wasn’t standardized until 2013 and Apple rarely implements new technology that hasn’t been standardized.  Looking at a [man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/8/system_profiler/) from 10.9 ([Mavericks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS#OS_X_10.9_Mavericks)) which was also released in 2013, the `-json` flag was not available.

It’s also not available in Mojave as the [man page](https://www.unix.com/man-page/mojave/8/system_profiler/) for that version doesn’t indicate the flag either.  I’ve tested it in Catalina and confirmed it exists there

Comment: I can confirm it's not in Mojave - there is `-xml` option, but no `-json` option. (Sometimes there can be undocumented options, so wanted to check the utility itself.)

Comment: @Allan, do you know when -xml switch was added?

Comment: I would have to check, but I believe it was in Mountain Lion.   I’ve got Tiger, so I’ll check that this weekend.

Comment: Actually nevermind, I found documentation from 2012 which mentions -xml switch, so its good enough for me.